# WSO2 APIM 3.2 is error: org.wso2.carbon.registry.RegistryException

Tags: wso2, deadlock, apim

WSO2 APIM 3.2 is error:
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to remove properties from resource version 392374. ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

```
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.removeProperties(JDBCResourceDAO.java:1811)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.removeResource(Repository.java:624)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.deleteNode(Repository.java:580)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.deleteSubTree(Repository.java:542)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.delete(Repository.java:455)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.delete(EmbeddedRegistry.java:855)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.deleteInternal(UserRegistry.java:879)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1100(UserRegistry.java:73)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$12.run(UserRegistry.java:854)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.